# Import csv data from a secure url into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have access to a system that if you enter in a url into a browser, it will automatically download a .csv file. The web address is formatted like below

```
https://secure.company.com/csv.cgi?user=username;password=password
```

What I would like to do is somehow get MS SQL Server 2012 to do all of the download and importing into a table automatically.

Is that even possible?
As a noob guess would it be done via a stored procedure?
If so how would one code such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like `wget` to download the file, then check out this [blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) for how to import the CSV file into the database.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your `wget` idea. I've never used that before.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there might be a way to send http request using SQL Server, using SQL queries, I’d strongly recommend you do this from C#. You can either develop a small application or use a CLR stored procedure for this.

Just update YourTable and download path and you should be fine.

```
protected const string FILE_NAME = @"C:\tablevalues.csv";

protected const string SQL_INSERT = "BULK INSERT YourTable FROM {0} WITH (         FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')";

protected void DownloadFile()
{
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("https://secure.company.com/csv.cgi?user=username;password=password", FILE_NAME);

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connection string");
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format(SQL_INSERT, FILE_NAME), sqlConnection);

sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection.Close();
sqlConnection.Dispose();
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to visual studio. How would I do it with a clr stored procedure?